# POST Beeps - was my mobo playing taps? Now it won't power on

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have an Asus P5Q Pro Turbo mobo.  I use it for a file server for home.

It's in a case with a total of 8 SATA drives, mostly the green eco type, of various brands.  Four are connected on the mobo, four more are on two add-on cards.

I was gone on a trip and my wife said the computer was beeping.  Eventually she powered it off.  When I got home, I noticed it beeped a series of beeps on startup and then the beeping stopped.  One drive couldn't be seen - figured bad hard drive.

However, after removing the drive, it still beeped.  On reboot, it couldn't see one drive, then another.  Tried removing some memory and cards - still beeping.  Finally it just suddenly powered off and now will not power on no matter what.  Tried different power source, etc.

Honestly, it ran fine for months...

I counted and there were 11 short-ish beeps during POST.  No Asus POST Code covers that.

It's a Yorktown-class processor, and I've got 8 SATA drives (and 1 rarely used DVD), along with 8GB of RAM, fans but nothing crazy.  No OC.

I'm wondering if:

(1) Is a 650W power supply too little?  It's an Antec EarthWatts.  Tried removing RAM, cards, but still no boot.  It did run fine for many months with this PS - if it was too small, wouldn't it have been too small all along?

(2) Or could the PS just be dead?  There IS a green light on the board (even though the system won't power on) so some juice is coming in.

(2) Anyone care to guess what 11 beeps in a row (and then silence) means?  Four beeps means power or temperature, according the ASUS POST doc I googled:

http://support.asus.com/pcassistant/pdf/BeepTable_en-us.pdf

I really don't think it's overheat - it's in a basement room and, well, it's February - ambient in this room is probably under 70F.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search shows that 11 beeps on an ASUS board means a bad L2 Cache.

Based on [Topic: [Problem]Post Codes](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20080415005820906&board_id=1&model=M3A&pa..):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Beeps            | Error Description                                                                                                                                                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1 short          | DRAM refresh failure; The programmable interrupt timer or programmable interrupt controller has probably failed.                                                   |
| 2 short          | Memory parity error; A memory parity error has occurred in the first 64K of RAM.  The RAM IC is probably bad.                                                      |
| 3 short          | Base 64K memory failure; A memory failure has occurred in the first 64K of RAM.  The RAM IC is probably bad.                                                       |
| 4 short          | System timer failure; The system clock/timer IC has failed or there is a memory error in the first bank of memory.                                                 |
| 5 short          | Processor error; The system CPU has failed.                                                                                                                        |
| 6 short          | Gate A20 failure; The keyboard controller IC has failed, which is not allowing Gate A20 to switch the processor to protected mode. Replace the keyboard controller.|
| 7 short          | Virtual mode processor exception error; The CPU has generated an exception error because of a fault in the CPU or motherboard circuitry.                           |
| 8 short          | Display memory read/write error; The system video adapter is missing or defective.                                                                                 |
| 9 short          | ROM checksum error; The contents of the system BIOS ROM does not match the expected checksum value.  The BIOS ROM is probably defective and should be replaced.    |
| 10 short         | CMOS shutdown register read/write error; The shutdown for the CMOS has failed.                                                                                     |
| 11 short         | Cache error; The L2 cache is faulty.                                                                                                                               |
| 1 long, 2 short  | Failure in video system; An error was encountered in the video BIOS ROM, or a horizontal retrace failure has been encountered.                                     |
| 1 long, 3 short  | Memory test failure; A fault has been detected in memory above 64KB.                                                                                               |
| 1 long, 8 short  | Display test failure; The video adapter is either missing or defective.                                                                                            |
| 2 short          | POST Failure; One of the hardware testa have failed.                                                                                                               |
| 1 long           | POST has passed all tests.                                                                                                                                         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Christopher N. Boisjoli has the correct answer, but for other readers searching about similar issues:  Google the term "beep code" and your specific motherboard manufacturer.  You should find a list of what different beep codes mean and what action you could take.